# Gruntfile - Warning Task "livereload-start" not found

Tags: gruntjs, yeoman

I am trying to run the following grunt command `grunt test:e2e` but this does not seem to work as I get the warning as pointed in the title. I don't want to post the entire gruntfile.js so I have supplied the gist link. I would really appreciate if someone can point me in the right direction.

[Gruntfile.js](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/c36c46da6a91be144574)

Answer (score 3):

The error should be your clue here; there are no task targets named "livereload-start". If you want to point to a specific task config given this structure:

```
connect: {
    target1: {
        // opts
    },
    target2: {
        // opts
    }
}
```

You would run `connect:target1` instead of `connect-target1`. If you remove `livereload-start` out of your task configuration (line 379), what happens?